# Entire + periodic in imaginary direction + bounded on the real line implies constant?

Tags: complex-analysis, maximum-principle

I was reading some slides from a lecture. In a proof, there arose the need to show a certain function $f : \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ was constant. The argument proceeded by checking that

1. $f$ was entire
2. $f(z+i) = f(z)$ for all $z$
3. $f$ was bounded on $\mathbb{R}$

and then concluding that $f$ must be constant. I followed the proofs of the three claims no problem, but my complex analysis is weak enough that I'm unsure how one is supposed to conclude that $f$ is constant. Clearly Liouville's theorem does not apply directly. My guess is that some kind of boundary principle is being applied to the "rectangle" $R = \{ z \in \mathbb{C} : 0 \leq \Im(z) \leq 1 \}$. For instance, if the maximum of $|f|$ on $R$ must occur on the boundary, then the result follows. My complex analysis is patchy enough, though, that I'm unaware if such a result.

---

**Added:**

- Relevant: [Lindelof's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindel%C3%B6f%27s_theorem)
- The above article contains an enlightening example. If we take $f(z) = \exp(\exp(2 \pi z))$,  then (1) and (2) are satisfied. (3) is "half satisfied" in the sense that $\lim_{t \to -\infty} f(z) = 1$ here.

Comment: I've just seen the edit you added while I was trying to find a counterexample...that's pretty close! Just put a minus sign and the function becomes bounded on $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @julien: Haha! Wow you're right. I was pretty dubious when I first read this "...pfffff what is this character talking about, how could introducing a minus sign affect anything..." but, yes, that works great! Nice work.

Comment: And I first thought there was a theorem proving boundedness...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need more assumptions to conclude that $f$ is constant. For instance, the function
$$
f(z)=\exp(-\exp(2\pi z))
$$
satisfies all your assumptions.

**Note:** I had not thought about that in a long time, and I first thought Hadamard's three-line theorem would prove boundedness on the strip. But my memory was playing me some trick, and boundedness on the strip is actually a requirement of the latter.